# How to generate live plot of the residuals vs. number of iteration while the driver is still running?

Tags: openmdao

My objective is while the driver/non-linear solver is still running, I would not only like to print the values of the inputs/outputs/gradients information but I would also like to generate a live plot for the residual of the objective function and other design variables/inputs/gradients of my interest. Residual of the objective function (or any other parameter) can be defined as log of the difference between two consecutive values.

I came across two particular features in Openmdao, driver/solver `debug_print` and driver/solver `recorder` features, where `debug_print` prints the input/output values live and information from the `recorder` is accessed to assess the convergence of the model. I have two specific questions:

1. How to save the values that `debug_print` prints on the screen in a text file (or other formats) while the driver is still running? (The text file is dynamically updated while the driver is running)
2. Can I use `recorder` to generate live plots of the residuals for the quantities of my interest? I have seen the *[Advanced recording tutorial](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/advanced_user_guide/recording/advanced_case_recording.html)* where `recorder` is used to plot the design variables and objective functions, but recorder information can be only retrieved once the driver/solver completes its job right? Or can the information in the recorder be retrieved while the driver/solver is still running? If the information from the recorder can be retrieved while the driver/solver is still running, I believe I can achieve my goal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a separate script to read the recorder values while the main script is running and writing those values. There is nothing stopping the reading script from being a different file/process from the main execution.

Comment: Thanks Justin! I am working on your suggestion and I have come up with an idea: A script continuously reads the .SQL file and writes the data in a text file, the script contains: `cr = om.CaseReader('cases.sql')` and `driver_cases = cr.get_cases('driver')` , if the size of `driver_cases` changes then the script immediately prints it at the end of the text file. However, there is one catch: The script does not know when to stop reading the .SQL file so it will go on forever. I wanted to know is there a specific delimiter that indicates the end of the .SQL file?

Comment: there is no delimiter like that. you would have to somehow watch for the end of the other process, or add something to your main script to write its own "done" file that you could watch for.